# Live Messenger Connect email contacts export

Tags: php, windows-live-messenger

Today at work I was asked to investigate a problem with contacts export from Hotmail. 
It was working last month when i wrote the library. For my surprise it indeed was not working. I investigated a bit and i noticed that Microsoft has done some updates to their API. The scopes were changed ... and the permissions that comes with the scopes. Here is the line that bothered me

> WL_Contacts.View - 
> View information about a user and the user's friends, with the exception of email addresses.

They stripped the priviledge of obtaining contacts email addresses :( 
What i have to do in order to get the e-mails back so i can use my exporter again ? 
Do you have problems with your contacts importers ? If not, what are you using ? Which scopes ? Are you doing separate requests for each user ?

Comment: I've read somewhere that i can submit my application for approval to Microsoft but i can't find it :( Do you have any idea where i can do that ?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you can find tons of information about the new Windows Live Connect API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243650.aspx) you can find version 5 of the API documentation.

If you want to sign up and create a Application you can do that [here](https://manage.dev.live.com).

I hope this is enough to get you started (unless you've already found the provided links).

Comment: Hmm thanks for the information. Sorry that i can't vote you up I don't yet have enough rating ... lol

Comment: Hmm ok another issue now. I had found free time to get this thing working. Corrected some stuff but i now receive "email hashes" ... lol. Not real emails :/ For some users i have IDs but i get empty results when i try to get info about them. Do you have any ideas how to access the user's email

This is pissing me so much that i'm about to write a msn messenger client just to download the contacts >.>

Comment: This doesn't give a specific answer to the problem.  How does one go about getting a list of contact emails through this api?